# UITableView checkmark has a white background

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, accessoryview

I customised tableview cell style with an imageview filling the entire cell. A checkmark is displayed when an UIAlertAction is called. But it displays a white box around the checkmark.

The background image shrinks when checkmark is displayed:

[image: 1]

and without the checkmark:

[image: 2]

I have tried:

let color = cell.contentView.backgroundColor
   cell.backgroundColor = color

in the tableview(cellforrowatindexpath) but it doesn't work.

How do I remove this white accessoryview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `accessoryview` you can use `imageview` to show Checked record.

Answer (score 1):

try to avoid editing with the override code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // the cells you would like the actions to appear needs to be editable
        return false
    }
```